# Nutch job failed to post to Solr

Tags: hadoop, solr, nutch

Environment: **NUTCH 1.6 & SOLR 4.2.1**.

Nutch & SOLR are running successfully. Posting to SOLR works well. But when trying to post from NUTCH, I am getting "Job failed".

Following command is used to run Nutch crawling and posting.

**bin/nutch crawl urls -solr http://10.10.10.10:8983/solr/tsdcr -dir crawl -depth 5 -topN 5 -threads 50**

**Output:**

```
SolrIndexer: finished at 2015-03-27 03:04:29, elapsed: 00:01:46
SolrDeleteDuplicates: starting at 2015-03-27 03:04:29
SolrDeleteDuplicates: Solr url: http://10.10.10.10:8983/solr/tsdcr
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1265)
  at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrDeleteDuplicates.dedup(SolrDeleteDuplicates.java:373)
  at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrDeleteDuplicates.dedup(SolrDeleteDuplicates.java:353)
  at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:153)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
  at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:55)
```

**Hadoop log:**

```
2015-03-26 03:04:00,832 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Resorting to protocol version default close connection policy
2015-03-26 03:04:00,832 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Should NOT close connection, using HTTP/1.1
2015-03-26 03:04:00,832 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.isResponseAvailable()
2015-03-26 03:04:00,832 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.releaseConnection()
2015-03-26 03:04:00,832 DEBUG httpclient.HttpConnection - Releasing connection back to connection manager.
2015-03-26 03:04:00,854 WARN  mapred.FileOutputCommitter - Output path is null in cleanup
2015-03-26 03:04:00,854 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0017
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.encode(Text.java:388)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.set(Text.java:178)
  at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrDeleteDuplicates$SolrInputFormat$1.next(SolrDeleteDuplicates.java:270)
  at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrDeleteDuplicates$SolrInputFormat$1.next(SolrDeleteDuplicates.java:241)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:236)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:216)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:48)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.